# How to change mouse scroll speed while using libinput?

Tags: mouse, bluetooth, xinput

I can only find scroll methods support in libinput.

https://www.mankier.com/4/libinput
http://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/group__config.html

How can I change the scroll speed of my bluetooth **mouse**? No relevant prop in my xinput list-props.

```
libinput Accel Speed (276):     0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (277):     0.000000
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (278):       0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (279):       0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (257):     1, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (258):        0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (259):        0, 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (280):     0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (281):     0
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (282):        0, 0, 1
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (283):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (284):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Button Scrolling Button (662): 2
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (663): 274
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (664):        0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (665):        0
```

Comment: @Sudanshu Did you find any solution for this ?

Comment: @SpiXel sadly no  :(

Comment: I am not sure if that's what you want, but `systemsettings5` of KDE does have `Mouse wheel scrolls by` textbox measured in lines. I bet other DEs have a similar option.

Answer (score 3):

This has been [answered on Unix  & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/307932) by [meuh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/119298/meuh)

In short,

> there is no current api for changing the scroll speed for libinput devices

so other methods must be used to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently doing [Speeding up the mouse wheel in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030678/speeding-up-the-mouse-wheel-in-ubuntu-18-04/1042722#1042722) as a work around. Not particularly happy about this workaround but it does work.

Answer (score 1):

Implementation of this feature has been [delegated to toolkits](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libinput/libinput/issues/185).

Here is a GNOME issue and two KDE issues tracking it:

- [Ability to set scroll speed in system settings](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/issues/950)
- [Libinput mouse KCM lost the scroll speed setting that was present in the evdev version](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=403842) and
- [Libinput touchpad KCM needs a scroll speed setting](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=403843)