# Speeding up the mouse wheel in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, mouse-scroll, mouse-wheel

I find I have to scroll a lot to move the text of my page compared to Windows where I can choose the speed of the mouse wheel.

Does Ubuntu have a similar utility and if so how can I access it?

Comment: Apparently there are differences between mouse wheel configurations if you are using Wayland or Xorg. On Wayland there isn't a way so far to adjust the speed. Do you know which graphics server are you using?

Comment: I am on wayland and would appreciate a link to confirm it is not editable, is it not even possible to modify the libinput to make it a global change?

Comment: If you care about [mouse scroll speed acceleration, see also here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1228224/kde-mouse-scrolling-acceleration/).

Comment: Here's my fix: [How to permanently fix scroll speed in Chrome, Sublime Text, Foxit PDF reader, and any other application you see fit](https://askubuntu.com/a/991680/327339). I can adjust the speed on an application-by-application basis since they don't all need the same amount of scroll speed adjustment.

Answer (score 38):

This solution worked for me with Ubuntu 18.04:

http://www.webupd8.org/2015/12/how-to-change-mouse-scroll-wheel-speed.html

```
sudo apt-get install imwheel   
cat > ~/.imwheelrc
".*"
None,      Up,   Button4, 8
None,      Down, Button5, 8
Control_L, Up,   Control_L|Button4
Control_L, Down, Control_L|Button5
Shift_L,   Up,   Shift_L|Button4
Shift_L,   Down, Shift_L|Button5
```

(the `8` at the end of the second and third line are the acceleration numbers, `3` is default)

Then add `imwheel --kill --buttons "4 5"` as a startup application:

[image: startup screenshot]

Comment: This worked for me, thanks; but why is it necessary? Is there a scroll-wheel-speed bug in Ubuntu 18?

Comment: Imwheel was working perfectly for me.
But then I have bought a new mouse with buttons 4 and 5.
Using your command it kills them.
Is there any other method?
Kind regards,

Comment: use `xev` to find out your mouse's actual button numbers for the wheel?

Comment: Work fine, but seems it affects my touchpad scrolling speed as well.

Comment: The difficulty of accomplishing such a basic task is embarrassing for the linux developers.

Answer (score 2):

May seem obvious but there is also the possibility of increasing scroll on a per-application basis, which may be all you need.

Comment: Bad idea if you have to do that on some applications (for example, firefox + libreoffice + gedit) because it's a lot of repetition, instead of speading it with OS parameters. This option is good to use if you want to slow down / increase that scroll speed in a particular app

Comment: @damadam Well but maybe you're not trying to actually deal with the entire OS in the first place, maybe it's just a problem you have with 1 or 2 particular applications. That was the point of my answer.

Comment: Yes, but how? Are you talking application-specific? I haven't seen this as an option in most programs.

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs The application would provide it. A good example is Firefox `about:config` + `mousewheel.min_line_scroll_amount`. Also any half-decent PC video game (that uses scrolling) ever.

Answer (score 1):

Cannot comment (only 31 of 50 needed reputation), so I have to write this as an answer:

`imwheel` works for Ubuntu 16.04, but the above answers destroys the Ctrl+Mousewheel from zooming text, which for some of us is commonly used.

The solution is to provide it for both Ctrl keys:

```
".+"
    @Exclude

".*chrome.*"
    @Priority=100
    None,      Up,   Button4, 3
    None,      Down, Button5, 3
    Shift_L,   Up,   Shift_L|Button4
    Shift_L,   Down, Shift_L|Button5
    Shift_R,   Up,   Shift_R|Button4
    Shift_R,   Down, Shift_r|Button5
    Control_L, Up,   Control_L|Button4
    Control_L, Down, Control_L|Button5
    Control_R, Up,   Control_R|Button4
    Control_R, Down, Control_R|Button5
```

The `Exclude` section is required so that it does NOT affect other apps (no idea why it would, but it does).

Answer (score 1):

Configuring `imwheel` does not work well for me in Ubuntu 20.04.
Changing `~/.imwheel` from

```
None,      Up,   Button4, 1
None,      Down, Button5, 1
```

to

```
None,      Up,   Button4, 3
None,      Down, Button5, 3
```

gives (me) a bad scrolling experience because the faster scrolling is achieved by scrolling in "jumps", not in a floating, faster manner.

However, I have a Logitech Wireless MX Master mouse and use [Solaar](https://pwr-solaar.github.io/Solaar/) (v1.0.1) to configure it. When configuring the mouse in Solaar, I can select "Wheel resolution" which gives me a much better and faster floating scroll experience.

[image: screenshot of Solaar configuration]

Answer (score 0):

On my ThinkPad, to change the scroll speed using the TrackPoint, inspired by [other answers here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/255890/how-can-i-adjust-the-mouse-scroll-speed/1391195#1391195), I did

```
xinput list
```

and found the TrackPoint to be id 14, so continued with

```
xinput list-props 14
```

under which I saw `libinput Scrolling Pixel Distance`. I set this using

```
xinput set-prop 14 'libinput Scrolling Pixel Distance' x
```

where `x` could be values between 10 and 50 (I experimented), lower values meaning faster scrolling.