# Mouse scroll speed

Tags: mouse

its been 4 years since people have asked how to set their mouse scroll speed. The imwheel solution is very hacky and has its problems (namely back/forward buttons stop working).

Will we please finally get a native GUI to setup the scroll speed.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! You would think that this was something that you could set in gnome-tweaks but no dice. Is this the link you followed? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030678/speeding-up-the-mouse-wheel-in-ubuntu-18-04 if so, you might want to try forgoing the part about killing certain buttons

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Speeding up the mouse wheel in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030678/speeding-up-the-mouse-wheel-in-ubuntu-18-04)