# How to permanently increase the number of lines scrolled with the mouse wheel

Tags: mouse, mouse-scroll, kde5

I use kubuntu 18.04 and the biggest number of lines you can scroll by mouse wheel is 12. 
With big monitor resolutions and long folder lists (not my doing) I would like to increase the number of lines to e.g. 20 to reduce my finger scrolling.

How can I do that in a way, that it stays permanently after reboot?

I have read, that imwheel should not be used anymore with 18.04.

Comment: It looks like people have had success with imwheel in 18.04 LTS.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030678/speeding-up-the-mouse-wheel-in-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: I tried it, it works at least after setup, I will see what it does after reboot. 
I will add it to autostart to be sure.

Comment: I had some weird effects with imwheel. I will check if that happens often. 

I had hopes that I could increase the limit 12 in the kde settings for the mouse, but that doesn't seem to be possible.